# Why Apache IoTDB reported error when including deviceid in the select statement?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0. I would like to ask why do I get an error as long as I include `deviceid` in the `select` statement of IoTDB? What should I change to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 1.1.x of Apache IoTDB, `deviceid` is marked as keyword so it cannot be used as naming choice. You can try to change the name of your root/time series and query again.